# SQL server ODBC driver linux username ''

Tags: sql-server, linux, odbc, driver

I installed the Microsoft SQL server ODBC driver for linux version 13.

I can login with username password commandline but not with the username and password within odbc.ini

Example

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/6/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo                                                                                                                                                                                                     yum install msodbcsql mssql-tools

[root@server01 etc]# cat odbc.ini

[MY_ODBC_DSN]

Driver = ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server

Server = tcp:10.10.10.1,1433

Database = demo

UID = user1

PWD = password
```

Does work

```
isql -v MY_ODBC_DSN user1 password
```

Doesn't Work

```
isql -v MY_ODBC_DSN

[28000][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Comment: Just learned it is not possible

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d4eab3b3-6254-4644-a1e4-e6866f7507fd/uid-in-odbcini?forum=sqldataaccess

Answer (score 6):

@Patrick, you can not read username and password from odbc.ini. I tried this with sqlcmd and here is how I verified it.

```
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-tools.list
exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.4.0
UsageCount=1
```

odbc.ini

```
[TestDB]
Server=myserver
Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
```

sqlcmd

```
sqlcmd -D -S TestDB -U myusername -P mypassword
```

If you would like to use integrated auth, check this out:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux/using-integrated-authentication
```